# WPF always focus on a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, focus

I want to always `Focus` on a specific `TextBox` on my WPF application whenever I click on anything on the application it should always focus on the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an event handler `MouseLeftMouseButton`. When the event handler was triggered, use `textbox.Focus()` inside the handler.

Comment: That would only work if the focus is lost by using the mouse. But what if somebody press the Tab-key ...?

Answer (score 7):

Add to the [TextBox.OnLostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onlostfocus.aspx) event a handler which sets the focus to the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm right, your intention is to get the keyboard commands and display the char pressed into your textbox even if the focus is on other controls.

If that is the case, you can route the keyboard commands to the root control (control in the top level... eg: window), **analyse them** and display in the textbox. I'ld try to give examples if that helps.

EDIT:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Shift)
  {
    if (e.Key > Key.A && e.Key < Key.Z)
    {
      textBox1.Text += e.Key.ToString().ToLower();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (e.Key > Key.A && e.Key < Key.Z)
    {
      textBox1.Text += e.Key.ToString();
    }
  }            
  e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Yes thats correct can you please give an example how to thanks!

Comment: Hey Tan, Check my edit. Now it's in your hands to analyze keys other than alphabets :)